# Android Studio Firebase Email Auth Not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a simple register feature using email / password and firebase but it doesn't seam to work. Nothing happens when I click on the register button on the app at all. I am not understanding what is wrong.

MainActivity

```
package com.joel.firebasetest1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button register;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email = findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
        password = findViewById(R.id.passwordTxt);
        register = findViewById(R.id.registerfinalBtn);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txt_email = email.getText().toString();
                String txt_pass = password.getText().toString();
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txt_email,txt_pass).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have registered successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joel.firebasetest1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FirebaseTest1">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle :project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle :module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.joel.firebasetest1"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }


    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Can someone please help me out? There are no errors displaying & I cant make this work at all.

- Just added a Log.w to check for warnings. Got the following. (There are many warning but I filtered it to Firebase ones only

  2021-03-25 20:33:12.812 1596-7009/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Config not found. Using empty config. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

  2021-03-25 20:33:12.840 1596-7009/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Did not find measurement config or missing version info. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

  2021-03-25 20:33:12.852 1596-7009/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Did not find measurement config or missing version info. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

  2021-03-25 20:33:13.037 1596-7009/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Did not find measurement config or missing version info. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

  2021-03-25 20:33:35.498 1596-7009/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Did not find measurement config or missing version info. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

  2021-03-25 20:35:06.663 7342-7447/? W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval

  2021-03-25 20:35:07.501 7472-7500/com.google.android.apps.messaging W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval

  2021-03-25 20:39:32.921 1596-7816/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Config not found. Using empty config. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

  2021-03-25 20:39:32.929 1596-7816/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Did not find measurement config or missing version info. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

  2021-03-25 20:39:32.936 1596-7816/com.google.android.gms W/FA-SVC: Did not find measurement config or missing version info. appId: com.joel.firebasetest1

There are also errors that came up:

```
2021-03-25 20:33:33.454 591-2766/system_process E/UserRestrictionsUtils: Unknown restriction queried by uid 1000 (com.android.providers.settings et al): com.joel.firebasetest1
2021-03-25 20:33:34.884 7108-7108/? E/AppButtonsPrefCtl: Exception when retrieving package:com.joel.firebasetest1
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.joel.firebasetest1
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:206)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:178)
        at com.android.settings.applications.appinfo.AppButtonsPreferenceController.retrieveAppEntry(AppButtonsPreferenceController.java:361)
        at com.android.settings.applications.appinfo.AppButtonsPreferenceController.refreshUi(AppButtonsPreferenceController.java:650)
        at com.android.settings.applications.appinfo.AppButtonsPreferenceController.refreshAndFinishIfPossible(AppButtonsPreferenceController.java:497)
        at com.android.settings.applications.appinfo.AppButtonsPreferenceController.handleActivityResult(AppButtonsPreferenceController.java:289)
        at com.android.settings.applications.appinfo.AppInfoDashboardFragment.onActivityResult(AppInfoDashboardFragment.java:412)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2810)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:325)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:289)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:128)
        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.onActivityResult(SettingsActivity.java:357)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-03-25 20:34:39.055 7556-7556/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.joel.firebasetest1
2021-03-25 20:34:39.062 7556-7556/? E/studio.deploy: Could not find apks for this package: com.joel.firebasetest1
2021-03-25 22:05:02.744 8224-8224/com.joel.firebasetest1 E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo Its not working. Like when I am launching the app and entering email / pass and clicking register nothing happens. I don't get any toast message what so ever also the user doesn't get registered

Comment: Have you tried to log the message if the Task is not successful?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have edited my original post and added the errors / warnings there.